# Executing multiple callouts from a future method

Tags: apex, callout, future, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a problem when I try to execute multiple callout from a method of an Apex Class.
The method code is the following:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static HttpResponse makeCallout(){
    List<Custom__mdt> customMetadata = [SELECT Email__c, Query__c, KPY_Code__c, Application_Parent__c, Application__c FROM Custom__mdt];

    if(customMetadata.isEmpty()) return;
    
    for(Custom__mdt record : customMetadata){

        List<sObject> count = Database.query(String.valueOf(record.get('Query__c')));
        Integer totalUniqueUsers = Integer.valueOf(count[0].get('expr0'));
        Date measurementDate = Date.today().addDays(-1);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('callout:my_Named_Credential');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);  
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('serviceDeskId', '34');
        gen.writeStringField('requestTypeId', '223');
        gen.writeFieldName('requestFieldValues');
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNumberField('customfield_11607', totalUniqueUsers);
            gen.writeStringField('customfield_11800', String.valueOf(record.get('KPY_Code__c')));
            gen.writeDateField('customfield_11606', measurementDate);
            gen.writeFieldName('customfield_11605');
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeStringField('value', String.valueOf(record.get('Application_Parent__c')));
                gen.writeFieldName('child');
                    gen.writeStartObject();      
                    gen.writeStringField('value', String.valueOf(record.get('Application__c')));
                    gen.writeEndObject();
                gen.writeEndObject();
            gen.writeEndObject(); 
        gen.writeEndObject();
        String jsonS = gen.getAsString();
        system.debug(jsonS);
        request.setBody(jsonS);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    return response;
```

When I try to execute this method I get the following error: 
**System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out** 
Can you explain me what is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: its seem after every callout, there is dml happening in the background. However, a Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement within the same transaction. Please confirm it in your case

Comment: i had used batch class to achieve this kind of implementation in the past instead of future method as execute method of batch will generate separate transaction for each scope

Comment: @Valentina I am not sure where your function get ends, Feel like inside the for loop you have an DML operation, API call get break on when you try to hit second time.